# How to check if Publishing feaure "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" is activated on site in sharepoint 2013 online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have to check if site has publishing feature activate or not. I have tried with `PublishingWeb.GetPublishing` web but it seems not working. When I deactivate the feature and debug again its showing me still `true`.

```
var pWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(context, context.Web);
                ctx.Load(pWeb);
                if (pWeb != null)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the *MSDN* documentation of [PublishingWeb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.publishingweb.aspx), it seems that does not ensure **SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure** is activated or not.

You can try following.

1. Find all activated features in a Site
2. Check if **SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure** exists or
   not

   ```
       using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(targetSite))
       {
           clientContext.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
           Web web = clientContext.Web;
           var site = clientContext.Site;
           var ativateFeatures = site.Features;
           clientContext.Load(ativateFeatures, features => features.Include(feature => feature.DisplayName, feature => feature.DefinitionId));
           clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

           var publishingFeature = ativateFeatures.FirstOrDefault(f => f.DisplayName == "PublishingSite");

           if (publishingFeature != null)
           {

           }
           else
           {

           }
       }
   ```

Comment: thank u atish wht if we just want to check the particular feature instead of going through all the features ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using javascript object model(jsom) if you.You can use design manager to get the exact feature id which you require.

Code here

```
var context = null;
var site = null;
var featureCollection;

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CheckFeatureIsEnabled, "SP.js");

function CheckFeatureIsEnabled(){
    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    site = context.get_site();
    featureCollection = site.get_features();
    context.load(featureCollection);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess,onFailure);
}

function onSuccess() {
    var listEnumerator = featureCollection.getEnumerator();
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        if (listEnumerator.get_current().get_definitionId() == '<Feature Id here>') {
            alert('Feature enabled');  
        }
    }  
}
function onFailure(sender, args) {
    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + 'n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```